# Vb.Net Messagebox pops up twice in ok button

Tags: vb.net

In my Login form I have a Filter: if the username and password input did not match, a messagebox will show. But, after I click the OK Button it will popup again.

I'm using the code Below..

```
Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click

    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    Dim name As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim tsPass As String
    Dim userName As String
    Dim type As String

    connect()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblUser", cn)

    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If rd.HasRows Then
        While rd.Read()
            name = rd("name").ToString()
            Password = rd("password").ToString()
            userName = rd("username").ToString()
            type = rd("usertype").ToString()

            tsPass = tbpassword.Text()
            frmMain.lblUser.Text = name

            If Password = tsPass And userName = tbusername.Text Then
                MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Logged in successfully as " & type, "Authentication Approved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Me.Hide()
                frmMain.ShowDialog()

                tbpassword.Text = ""
                tbusername.Text = ""
            Else
                'MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                tbpassword.Text = ""
                tbusername.Text = ""
                MsgBox("Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) 'THIS MESSAGE POPUP TWICE
            End If
        End While
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know vb.net but this might be relevant: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?662450-RESOLVED-Need-help-to-clear-text-box-after-MessageBox-OK-Click

Comment: I cant visit vbforums.com. It says "Sorry. The administrator has banned your IP address."

Comment: maybe incognito/private browsing mode will help

Comment: I'm sorry Noam Hacker. But I really don't get your point

Comment: You should exit the loop after success or failure of authentication. Use a `Goto` or `Exit While`.

Comment: I wish I can see some relevant snippets. tnx

Comment: actually I solved my problem. tnx @Xaqron